# Trying to update, but it's forcing me to install 15.04 alpha

Tags: 14.04, update-manager

I went to do a regular update of my ubuntu 14.04 but for some reason it's asking me if i want to do a partial upgrade. When i select Continue instead of the Partial Upgrade option i get the following message:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the output of apt-get update?

Comment: It looks like I had some 14.10 and 15.04 repos in my repo list. I removed them and the update process is working properly now. Thanks!

Comment: RjPinton (or @xangua) Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Fabby, done :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I had some 14.10 and 15.04 repos in my repo list. I removed them and the update process is working properly now. Thanks!